# The Best way to Access related field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a very unique situation where I have inherited a compiled application but no source to alter it. As such I wish to temporarily extend the system in order to buy a few weeks in order to rewrite it.

First of all let me lay down A small example database to make things easier to understand.

```
Table Team

ID         Name           City
1          Fish           Carson City
2          Rats           Springfiled
3          Salamanders    Lubboch


Table Players

ID        Team_ID         Name
1         1               Bill
2         1               Ted
3         2               Moe
4         3               Al
5         3               Stan
```

Looking at a configuration file I can see that the application is using the following configuration string is used to produce the following SQL query.

Configuration String:    `ID,Team_ID,Name`

SQL QUERY  `SELECT ID,Team_ID,Name FROM Players WHERE ID = 2`

I cannot edit the SQL query BUT I can edit the config string

Of course the result is:      `2,  1,  Ted`

But this is not optimal. What I really would like to result to be is:  `2,  Fish,  Ted`

Given that I cannot access the code that generates the query and that's I cannot alter the query other than to change the configuration string.

As I am not an advanced SQL user, I lay awake at night thinking I wish there was a way to insert the following pseudo-query the configuration string.

Configuration String:    `ID,team.name(Team_ID),Name`

SQL QUERY  `SELECT ID,team.name(Team_ID),Name FROM Players WHERE ID = 2`

I do have full Rights to the database. Can anyone think of a way I can add a stored or calculated or something with the name that will allow me to query this way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A simple join `select p.id, t.name, p.name from Players p join Teams t on p.Team_id=t.id` will get you a table of player_id, team_name, player_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to insert a dependent subquery into the configuration string:

```
ID,(SELECT Name FROM Team WHERE ID = Players.Team_ID),Name
```

if this works with your application is another question...

Maybe try this, which keeps column names as they are:

```
ID,(SELECT Name FROM Team WHERE ID = Players.Team_ID) AS Team_ID,Name
```